# Reusing client certificate for TLS proxy with nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, load-balancing, tcp

I have a TCP application that uses mutual TLS to authenticate connecting clients.
Because of increased traffic I'd like to clusterize the application and load-balance the nodes with nginx. I already have that working with nginx's `stream` module, which (to my understanding) acts as a layer 4 balancer.

At this point it seems reasonable to me to drop connection attempts that fail the mTLS verification immediately at nginx, so the upstream nodes don't have to bother with them.
However, this means that I would have to terminate the TLS connection at nginx. Unfortunately my application relies on getting the client's identity from the verified client cert.

Is there any way to have the mTLS check at nginx, and then reusing the client certificate for the upstream connection?

For HTTP applications I have seen the workaround to terminate the TLS connection at nginx and pass the client cert as a custom header (e.g. `proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_cert;`), but that obviously wouldn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You can't both terminate the connection and keep it end-to-end.

But if you *trust* your proxy, your proxy can simply inject a header and use it's own client certificate to authenticate that the connection is trustworthy and initiated by a given client certificate.